# Boundedness of quadratic forms

Tags: quadratic-forms, quadratic-programming

How can I prove that a function in quadratic form $F(x)=1/2 (x^TAx) + b^T x + c$ is either bounded below or above?

What does it imply in terms of convexity of the function?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are missing a condition on $A$.

Comment: And/or a condition on $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the matrix 
\begin{align}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & - 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
and $b = 0$ vector and $c = 0$, then we have the function
\begin{align}
F(x, y) = \frac{1}{2} (x, y) 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & - 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}
= \frac{1}{2}( x^2-y^2)
\end{align}
which is neither bounded above nor below.